# Office Addin VSTO install error on a specific system

Tags: vsto, office-addins

Our VSTO for installing our Office Word Addin works correctly on all systems tested so far, both in-house and on (almost) all customer systems.
However, on one customer system it is failing.
An attempt to manually install the VSTO results in this error message being displayed: 'Store metadata "ApplicationSourceUri" is not valid'.

We have checked for all the known requirements on the system (Addin certificate, trusted publisher flags in the registry, Office 2010 runtime, etc), but we have yet to find a cause.  Online research has so far has not returned an answer.

Any help would be much appreciated!

A VSTO install log generated by Windows gives this error information:

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * An exception occurred while downloading the manifest. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Store metadata "ApplicationSourceUri" is not valid.
ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [27.04.2018 20:57:19] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentException (SubscriptionState)
        - Store metadata "ApplicationSourceUri" is not valid.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.GetPropertyString(DefinitionAppId appId, String propName)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.GetPropertyUri(DefinitionAppId appId, String propName)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.GetSubscriptionStateInternal(DefinitionIdentity subId)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.GetSubscriptionStateInternal(SubscriptionState subState)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.CheckAndReferenceApplication(SubscriptionState subState, DefinitionAppId appId, Int64 transactionId)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.BindCore(Boolean blocking, TempFile& tempDeploy, TempDirectory& tempAppDir, FileStream& refTransaction, String& productName)

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove a corresponding to your application a windows registry key (associated with application):

```
 HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Deployment\SideBySide\2.0\PackageMetadata
```

Then try to re-build and publish it anew.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Eugene!  Actually, our Addin does not write anything to that registry path.